# Do UK tax rules allow you to hold Bitcoin in a SIPP?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, cryptocurrency

Do United Kingdom tax rules allow you to hold Bitcoin in a self-invested pension plan?

Comment: No. I seriously doubt if any of the firms providing SIPP would allow you to. My next question is why would you want to do so ? Bitcoin for pension, seriously ??

Comment: @DumbCoder Lots of reasons why.  Could be a big bet on Bitcoin being more widely adopted i.e anticipating Bitcoin denominated annuities.  Or could just be a punt on Bitcoin appreciating (free of capital gains tax in a SIPP).

Comment: So you intend to loose your pension on a whim ? Is that why people go for a pension, to take a punt ? `Bitcoin denominated annuities` Not going to happen so quickly on an asset which is outside the control of anybody.

Comment: @DumbCoder doesn't have to happen quickly.  Pensions are long term!

Comment: @DumbCoder That is assuming the pension is 100% invested in bitcoin. I would surmise that bitcoin would represent the small percentage of high-risk investment that people tend to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prudential has a list of allowable investments for their SIPP, though I'm not sure if these are industry standard: http://www.pruadviser.co.uk/new_pdf_folder/FRPM10011.PDF

Looks like if they consider Bitcoin a commodity, it will probably not be allowed. But the UK is [considering regulating Bitcoin as a currency](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304360704579415352635879152), which means that you may be able to have it qualify under this rule:

- Deposit accounts in any currency
  with an EEA authorised deposit
  taker opened by an appointed
  investment manager.

Of course it will be hard to fit those standards. It looks like [some countries](http://www.leaprate.com/forex-industry-news/entry/germany-becomes-first-country-to-formally-recognize-and-regulate-bitcoin.html) in the EEA do  regulate Bitcoins so you may need to open an account with them.

Comment: Thank you. UK tax authority statement on sales tax treatment of Bitcoin http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/briefs/vat/brief0914.htm

Comment: The second link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. I have a SIPP with Hargreaves Lansdown and I transferred one of my smaller old GMP pots to start it. I took the £8,000 transfer and put it in the the two XBT BITCOIN ETFs with HL.

Comment: This was attracting "not an answer" flags, which didn't seem correct to me as it does answer the question. I've edited it to remove some of the irrelevant points. If you still think it's not an answer, please use a comment or a custom flag to explain why.

Comment: No, but you can use an exchange traded fund as a proxy for Bitcoin is really quite a sensible answer. If you are going to take a punt on Bitcoin, might as well do it tax efficiently. Could be a little less anecdotal though,